# Custom link on facebook comment field in facebook app

Tags: facebook, comments, xfbml, facebook-page

We have created a facebook-app which contains a fb:comment field. We have included the app on a fanpage. All works well so far, but when a user comments in the app on the fanpage and chooses to show comment on his/hers wall, the link that appears over the comment links to the app page and not to the fanpage.

Is it possible to customize the link to point to the fanpage instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do this. Your best bet is including a link to your fan page on your application page.